# How to change text bold using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am a programming beginner. I would like to develop a simple Chrome extension that allows to bold for dragged content, when I click a button in popup.html. I succeeded to make bold for dragged content, when I click a default icon, but making a button in popup.html with the function required more complex way.

I think that popup.js is necessary to send a message to content.js to trigger the function boldText(). I struggled to use chrome.tabs.sendMessgge or other things to trigger the function, but I failed.
Please give me some advice.

Here is my code:

*1. manifest.json*

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "test",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "description": "test",

 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["<all_urls>"],
    "js":         ["content.js"]
 }],

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.3.1.slim.js", "background.js"]
 },

 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
 ]
}
```

*2. background.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);
function buttonClicked(tab) {
  let msg = {
    txt: "hello"
  }
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
}
```

*3. content.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.txt === "hello") {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    alert(selection);
    boldText();
  }
}

function boldText() {
  document.designMode = "on"; // designMode on for execCommand
  document.execCommand('Bold', false);
  document.designMode = "off"; // designMode off for execCommand
  return false;
}
```

*4. popup.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="boldButton" value="bold">bold</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener in your `background.js` file won't work because the browser action icon has an associated popup. You have the perform the logic of that listener in your `popup.js` file (not shown).

Comment: Well, popup.js was mess, so I deleted the code and tried to write down new one. You mean that the contents in background.js should be moved to content.js, do I catch up right?

Comment: No. Review the [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked): the browser action icon can have EITHER a popup window OR a `onClicked` event listener, but NOT BOTH. You must choose which behaviour you want.